# How can I avoid replacing "this" by webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to write a library to make "routine" easy. So, I began to write it using Webpack and babel and... I met a problem... Webpack replaces all `this`'s by `undefined`'s

Here is the code of one method:

```
let div = document.querySelector('.test');
div.style.color = 'black';

Node.prototype.UX = {

    toggleable(elem, prop, value) {

        let elemsState = elem.style[prop];

        this.onclick = () => {    
            if (!elem.dataset.state || elem.dataset.state == "0") {
                elem.dataset.state = "1";
                elem.style[prop] = value;
            } else {
                elem.dataset.state = "0";
                elem.style[prop] = elemsState;
            }
        }
    }
};

let button = document.querySelector('#test');

button.UX.toggleable(div, 'color', 'red');
```

and here is what browser gets:

[image: Chrome DevTools]

It works fine without Webpack. But I want to write the library with Webpack because it makes possible to use ES6 and it's convenient.

So, how could I fix the problem?

Comment: It's never a good idea to re-write or extend native JS classes such as `Node`.

Comment: if I would want to write my own classes the same problem will appear again

Comment: `webpack replaces all "this"'es by "undefined"` - I can't recall the circumstances that *babel* does this too - it's a pain, but I can't see why webpack has moved `let elemsState = elem.style[prop];` inside the onclick, nor why it has inserted a `console.log("I work!");` into your code!!

Comment: @JaromandaX hahahaha dude :D actually I did it because `let elemsState` must be earlier and `console.log` isn't necessary here

Comment: @JaromandaX so screenshot is oldish

Comment: yeah, I figured it wasn't the issue. your code transpiles in babel just fine, what transpiler does webpack use?

Comment: I suspected that, so why does https://babeljs.io/repl/ transpile your code properly!

Comment: Babel is replacing **module level** `this` with `undefined` because that's the right thing to do  (`this` inside modules is `undefined`). Of course in your code you don't have a module level `this`. Which version of Babel are you using?

Comment: @JaromandaX doesn't your babel work the same way?

Comment: @FelixKling yeah, I know it works right. But how can I change this behaviour?

Comment: I pasted the code in the question into babel and this was this not undefined

Comment: You can pass `modules: false` as an option to whichever Babel preset you are using.

Comment: You are saying this works fine without Webpack? Can you make a runnable demo with relevant HTML?

Comment: Right, could you replace your bottom lines with this: let button = document.querySelector('#test');
let bound = button.UX.toggleable.bind(button);
bound(div, 'color', 'red'); and check if that works

Comment: @mrsq your solution works as well :)

Comment: You're welcome, your `this` keyword wasn't being bound as you intended, but .bind will set your context as you need it.